# CLI - Ignore a line when using the for command

Tags: parsing, for-loop, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I'm trying to set a variable which will identify the make of a laptop.

I am doing this by using the command

wmic csproduct get vendor

This gives the following output

Vendor
LENOVO
(blank)

So based on that command, I have used the for command in the way below, to try and set a variable with the value 'LENOVO'

> for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %i in ('wmic csproduct get vendor')
>   do set vendor=%i

however, problem is that the output of the wmic command actually produces a blank line, under the word LENOVO, so my variable gets set as a blank value. Is there anyway to stop the for command from parsing this 3rd line, therefore stopping once the variable has been set with the value of 'lenovo'?

The skip function works fine, and bypasses the first line completely. However it doesn't seem to give me the option to say for example, skip lines 1 and 3 but leave 2. I have experimented with the EOL parameter to try and ignore the blank line, but the for command still reads the empty 3rd line each time.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little whacky, but try using the following within your line. It will filter out the Vendor line and then sort alphabetically, putting the blank line first. If you really need to do stuff like this regularly, check into a Windows port of some Unix utils like sed and awk.

```
wmic csproduct get vendor | find /v /i "vendor" | sort
```

Comment: Fantastic John. Thank you kindly. I am happy to accept this as the answer.